# how to convert from html number to symbol?

Tags: html, html-entities

After searching internet for a while, I found that there are a lot of online tool that allow conversion from symbol to html number, but not for vice versa.

I am looking for tool/online tool/php script to convert from html number back to symbol

eg:

```
& -> &#38;
```

then back to

```
&#38; -> &
```

Does anyone know of this?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in java using :

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils
```

and using the `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(String str) method`

eg output :

```
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("&#64;")); 
@
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("&#8364;"));
-
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("&#8211;"));
€
```

Answer (score 2):

Roll your own ;)

For PHP: A google search found [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html-entity-decode/):

```
<?php
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

$a = htmlentities($orig);

$b = html_entity_decode($a);

echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now


// For users prior to PHP 4.3.0 you may do this:
function unhtmlentities($string)
{
    // replace numeric entities
    $string = preg_replace('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('~&#([0-9]+);~e', 'chr("\\1")', $string);
    // replace literal entities
    $trans_tbl = get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES);
    $trans_tbl = array_flip($trans_tbl);
    return strtr($string, $trans_tbl);
}

$c = unhtmlentities($a);

echo $c; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now

?>
```

For .NET You could write something as simple that uses [HTMLEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode(VS.71).aspx) or [HTMLDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmldecode(VS.71).aspx). For example:

**HTMLDecode**

*[Visual Basic]*

```
Dim EncodedString As String = "This is a &ltTest String&gt."
Dim writer As New StringWriter
Server.HtmlDecode(EncodedString, writer)
Dim DecodedString As String = writer.ToString()
```

*[C#]*

```
String EncodedString = "This is a &ltTest String&gt.";
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Server.HtmlDecode(EncodedString, writer);
String DecodedString = writer.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of these numbers are just ASCII or unicode values I believe, so all you need to do is look up the symbol associated with that value.  For non-unicode symbols, this could be as simple as (python script):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

# Iterate through all command line arguments
for entity in sys.argv:
    # Extract just the digits from the string (discard the '&#' and the ';')
    value = "".join([i for i in entity if i in "0123456789"])
    # Get the character with that value
    result = chr(value)
    # Print the result
    print result
```

Then call it with:

```
python myscript.py "&#38;"
```

This could presumably be translated to php or something else very easily, something based on:

```
<?php
$str = "The string ends in ampersand: ";
$str .= chr(38); /* add an ampersand character at the end of $str */

/* Often this is more useful */

$str = sprintf("The string ends in ampersand: %c", 38);
?>
```

(taken from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) as I don't know php!).  Of course, this will need modifying to convert "&" into 38, but I'll leave that as an exercise for someone who knows php.